# My Windows 8.1/Ubuntu 12.04 dual boot won't boot windows after updating to v 8.1

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-8

I've searched the internet for similar problems, but I couldn't find an answer. Thus, my question is:

After upgrading my windows 8 to 8.1, I am no longer able to boot windows from the GRUB menu. Ubuntu still functions fine. Whenever I select the option to boot windows, the screen goes to black.

Comment: @user68186 sees to be the exact opposite instead, so it's not a duplicate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows 8 wont boot after installation of 12.10](http://askubuntu.com/questions/211339/windows-8-wont-boot-after-installation-of-12-10) or also of [Installed Ubuntu My Windows 8 Not Booting](http://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/installed-ubuntu-my-windows8-not-booting).